# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException Parameter value [com..schoolmanagement.model.exam.QuestionPaper@7d78f8f] did not match expected type

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, jpa

I declared a two classes, `QuestionPaper`

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Component
public class QuestionPaper {
    @Id
    private String id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "courseId")
    private Course course;
    private String paperTitle;
    private String paperDsc;
    private String duration;
    private Date dateCreated = new Date();
    private Date lastUpdated;
    private String paperCode;
    private String createdById;

}
```

and `Question`

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
public class Question {
    @Id
    private String id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "courseId")
    private Course course;
    private int questionNo;
    private String question;
    private String answerOne;
    private String answerTwo;
    private String answerThree;
    private String answerFour;
    private String correctAnswer;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "questionPaperId")
    private QuestionPaper questionPaper;

}
```

My Database is postgres
i created a question paper

[image: element in table question paper]

Now whenever i am try to get list of questions by QuestionPaper

```
List<Question> questionList = questionRepository.findAllByQuestionPaperOrderByQuestionNoAsc(questionPaperService.getQuestionPaperById(questionPaperId).get());
```

i am getting following exceptions

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException Parameter value [com.chaitanya.schoolmanagement.model.exam.QuestionPaper@7d78f8f] did not match expected type [com.chaitanya.schoolmanagement.model.exam.QuestionPaper (n/a)];

Comment: Do you use multiple`ClassLoader`s?

Comment: No actually i dont have any idea about class loader

Comment: According to your tags, you use spring boot? Can you try to reproduce the problem in a new project as simple as possible (as few code/configuration/dependencies) as possible?

Comment: yes i used spring boot

Comment: 1. Why is `QuestionPaper` an `@Component` it shouldn't be 2. you must implement a proper `equals` and `hashCode` method, neither of one you did (note don't use Lombok to generate the `equals` and `hashCode` method! See [this](https://deinum.biz/2019-02-13-Lombok-Data-Ojects-Arent-Entities/)), see [this](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-implement-equals-and-hashcode-using-the-jpa-entity-identifier/) for a proper implementation